# How can I use images that are on the server locally?

Tags: images, migration, localhost

I will try to explain myself as best as possible:

- I have a live WordPress website which has over 600 posts and 1000 images used in these posts.
- I have a local copy running at `http://localhost/my-wordpress-site`.
- I use [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to export posts from the live site.
- When I export with WP Migrate DB, it finds and replaces the live site URL (//my-wordpress-site.com) with the local URL (//localhost/my-wordpress-site) so that links will work locally.

The problem I have is that it changes the links to all the images. My goal is to keep the image links the same (i.e. pointing to the images on the servers) so I don’t have to download thousands of images to my local machine.

How can I keep the images URLs pointing to the images on the server? Do I have to modify the DB directly?

Comment: If you're referring to any images that are placed in post/page content via the text-editor, this isn't something that you can just change a table or two in the db and it will apply everywhere. There is a wp_posts table that shows the data for all posts and a "content" column, but you'll be there literally forever trying to go that route. If you change the site url or home url, that's going to affect your local url. Try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-url-path-enabler/

Comment: Also you can try this method if that plugin doesn't help, this is a code method without tinkering with the database: http://blog.room34.com/archives/5091

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "siteurl" and "home" in your wp_options table. The rest of the paths should stay the same then.